# How to detect if Media Queries are present using Modernizr

Tags: media-queries, modernizr, yepnope

I'm trying to detect whether media queries are present using Modernizr 2, then loading in respond.js if appropriate.

I've put this in my script.js file...

```
Modernizr.load({
  test: Modernizr.mq,
  yep : '',
  nope: 'mylibs/respond.js'
});
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm really surprised there isn't an example of how to do this with Media Queries on the Modernizr site. Here is the version of Modernizr I'm using...

http://www.modernizr.com/download/#-backgroundsize-borderradius-boxshadow-iepp-respond-mq-cssclasses-teststyles-testprop-testallprops-prefixes-domprefixes-load

Comment: By the way, I'm loading Modernizr before my script.js just in case anyone is wondering.

Comment: You don't need the empty `yep`.

Answer (score 19):

That's because `!!Modernizr.mq === true` at all times... you're testing for the wrong thing!

As per the [docs](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#mq):

> If a browser does not support media queries at all (eg. oldIE) the mq() will always return false.

But this: `Modernizr.mq()` is `false` too! You have to actually test for something. Here, the `all` keyword is just what you need (or `only all` as Paul suggests):

```
Modernizr.load({
  test: Modernizr.mq('only all'),
  nope: 'polyfill.js'
});
```

However, all custom builds of Modernizr **2.0.x** with `mq` include [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond), so you never really need to test this, except if you want to load another polyfill instead. In that case, you will need to disable/remove respond.js from your build.

#### Modernizr 2.5.x

With the arrival of Modernizr 2.5.x, the above is no longer true. The [abbreviated changelog](http://www.modernizr.com/news/modernizr-25) specifies that:

> We no longer include Respond.js in the builder because it was creating crashing conflicts in IE8. If you still require Respond.js in your project, just include it manually.

This means `Modernizr.mq('only all')` *may* now return `false`...

Comment: Thanks Felix, I'll give this a try tonight.

Comment: `'only all'` is slightly better. I'd recommend that.

Comment: Gah, still can't get this to work guys :-(

      <!-- All JavaScript at the bottom for fast page loading, except for Modernizr which enables HTML5 elements & feature detects -->
 <script type="text/javascript"
  src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js">
 </script>
 
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
  Modernizr.load({
    test: Modernizr.mq('only all'),
    nope: 'js/polyfills/respond.js'
  });
 </script>

Comment: still don't understand how to format code in these comments 'code' test?

Comment: Doesn't Modernizr include respond.js anyway? So you wouldn't need to load it up? For the comments, you have to use `\`backticks\``.

Comment: Hmmm does Modernizr 'conditionally' load respond.js though, or just include it anyway?

Comment: @SparrwHawk `Modernizr.mq('only all')` being true tells you that the current page supports the `.mq()` method and that it meets `'only all'`. It does *not* tell you if the current page natively supports media queries. Just use a Modernizr build that includes respond.js

Comment: @ryanve All custom builds with `mq` include respond.js, except if you explicitly disable it.

Answer (score 2):

**Just noticed this conclusion is reached in the comments of Felix's answer** *- I'm leaving my answer here in case it helps other visitors who, like me, did not get it.*

Not sure if this is still an issue but if you are loading Modernizr v2.0.6 you shouldn't need to run this test. Just adding it to your page should automatically fire-up respond.js and your media queries should start working.

I've been scratching my head over this as well since I kept getting "true" returned in IE8!! Poorly explained on the Modernizr site but alluded to in the http://html5boilerplate.com/ (first instance)

Comment: +1 Right, I thought it was pretty clear... but then again, that was after reading Modernizr's source. Reading source is good.